# Show HTML code (with JavaScript) within an Excel worksheet

Tags: javascript, html, excel, vba

I'm creating an Excel application, but need to show already-created webpages (in order not to rewrite the code again in VBA). I'm trying to embed the HTML+JavaScript code into an Excel worksheet (without opening an instance of the webbrowser), but I'm not able.

Any similar experience? Is it possible? Thank you very much.

Comment: Why does this require that you not use a WebBrowser Control?

Answer (score 0):

You must have a browser instance in order to view an html file correctly, especially if you want JavaScript interaction. However, IE is embeddable and can be called from Excel.